# Generate CSV(MS-DOS) file using Java

Tags: java, excel

```
File file = new File("F:\\New Projcts\\Ex\\hello.csv");
file.createNewFile();
```

It generate only `.CSV(Comma delimited)` but not in `.CSV(MS-DOS)`

how to create `.CSV(MS-DoS)` file in java

Comment: do you mean you get an issue with char set?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your issue is about the charset and not about the choice of CSV pattern. In Java, output stream uses the default charset, i.e. dixit *Charset.defaultCharset()* javadoc: the default charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and typically depends upon the locale and charset of the underlying operating system.

Unless you are working with a very old MSDOS os, it'd never be the case. The charset has to be specified with something like:

```
OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("FileFromNonJavaProgram.txt"), "Cp850" /* MS-DOS Latin-1 */);
```